# How can I print a "test-page" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I'm new to Windows 7. I have installed a new printer, and I would like to print a "test-page". I know how to do this in earlier versions of Windows, but it seem to have changed now in Windows 7. How can I print a "test-page" in Windows 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Devices and Printers by clicking the Start button

And then clicking Devices and Printers.

Right-click a printer, and then click Printer properties.

On the General tab, click Print Test Page.

Comment: Thanks, I tried "Properties" before, but "Printer properties" worked better!

Answer (score 1):

I find it's sometimes easier just to use [ecotestpage.com](http://ecotestpage.com) to print a test page.

This page does not use as much ink/toner as many default printer test pages.